# Features used by MAUI key phrase extraction tool

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp

I have been trying out keyphrase extraction for a while and I want to know what are all the features that MAUI [MAUI github](https://github.com/zelandiya/maui-standalone) uses for training the keyphrase extraction?

Having read [this](https://www.airpair.com/nlp/keyword-extraction-tutorial) its hard for me to understand every feature that she uses can someone help me give a brief about the features that she is using? and some references for the same if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The references are in the link that you give: [here](http://community.nzdl.org/kea/index_old.html) you can find references to two papers which describe the method:

- [Domain-Specic Keyphrase Extraction](http://community.nzdl.org/kea/Frank-et-al-1999-IJCAI.pdf)
- [KEA: Practical Automatic Keyphrase Extraction](http://community.nzdl.org/kea/Nevill-et-al-1999-DL99-poster.pdf)

Fyi it seems there's no neural nets involved (the question is tagged with neural-network)

Comment: removed the NN tag =D thanks for the references.